# Updating Pytorch variables

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

First, I should mention I’m on torch version 0.3.1, but am happy to upgrade if necessary.

I am still learning, so please let me know if I misunderstood anything here.

I am building several graphs imperatively, using Variables. The mathematical expressions might be quite complicated as time goes on, and certain parts of the graphs may be generated using autograd’s gradient functions, which may then be operated on.

I can create whatever expression I want just fine. The only catch is building up this graph can be quite “slow” - for relatively simple operations (4x4 matrices being multiplied together), it can take a few ms.

Once these graphs are generated, though, I expect that I should be able to update certain Variables’ values, and evaluate the output of the graph (or any node, really), much faster. I believe that that is probably the case since evaluation should be able to happen completely in the C back-end, which should be pretty otimized for speed? In other words, building the graph in python might be slow, since it involves python for loops and the like, but re-evaluating a graph with static topology should be fast.

Is this intuition correct? If so, how can I efficiently re-assign a value and re-evaluate the graph?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about updating values of input variables, and you just want to evaluate the forward of the graph and are not going to call `.backward()`, you can use `volatile=True` on the input `Variable`(s) in Pytorch 0.3.

This feature is removed in 0.4 in favor of the context manager `with torch.no_grad():`.

This is usually done at inference time. If you do this, the graph won't be created, thus eliminating the overhead.

## Update

### Pytorch 0.3

From Pytorch 0.3 docs:

> Volatile is recommended for purely inference mode, when you’re sure you won’t be even calling .backward(). It’s more efficient than any other autograd setting - it will use the absolute minimal amount of memory to evaluate the model. volatile also determines that requires_grad is False.

and

> Volatile differs from requires_grad in how the flag propagates. If there’s even a single volatile input to an operation, its output is also going to be volatile. Volatility spreads across the graph much easier than non-requiring gradient - you only need a single volatile leaf to have a volatile output, while you need all leaves to not require gradient to have an output that doesn’t require gradient. Using volatile flag you don’t need to change any settings of your model parameters to use it for inference. It’s enough to create a volatile input, and this will ensure that no intermediate states are saved.

So if you use Pytorch 0.3 and want to do efficient inference, you use `volatile=True` on your inputs.

### Pytorch 0.4

The context manager has been introduced in Pytorch 0.4. From The Pytorch [migration guide between 0.3 and 0.4](https://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html):

> The volatile flag is now deprecated and has no effect. Previously, any computation that involves a Variable with volatile=True wouldn’t be tracked by autograd. This has now been replaced by a set of more flexible context managers including torch.no_grad(), torch.set_grad_enabled(grad_mode), and others.

So when you say: *"Then, if there is a way to turn all variables of that graph to non-volatile, I can just perform inference."*, setting the input as `volatile` or using `no_grad` will do exactly this.

As for the example of using `torch.no_grad()`, look at the `test` function in [this script](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py).

### Static graphs during training

I'm not aware of any method to avoid the creation of the graph at each iteration in training mode in Pytorch. Dynamic graphs come at a cost. If you want this, convert your model to Tensorflow/Caffe2/any library supporting static graphs, even though in my experience they won't necessarily be faster.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The only problem with this solution is that you can't get the gradients of something that is volatile.  The graph topology should be static whether or not gradients are being computed or not with respect to a changing variable. Is there a way to change a value that gradients are being computed with respect to?

Comment: Now that I think about it, this might still work.  If I take a gradient using autograd, I create a new graph, if I understand this correctly.  Then, if there is a way to turn all variables of that graph to non-volatile, I can just perform inference.  I'm guessing the context manager is a cleaner way to do this, is that correct?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of how you would use this in pytorch 0.4?

Comment: Updated to answer your questions